# Show Gridview footer inside updatepanel

Tags: gridview, updatepanel, footer

I have a simple situation that does not work.

Gridview is nested inside updatepanel with functionality such as insert, edit, cancel, update, sort etc. Everything works fine, but now I have added Insert Row button in gridview header to show gridview header using grdView.ShowFooter. Button gets clicked, event gets fired, ShooFooter returns true, but no footer is being showed. I tried loading gridview with showfooter=true, and footer gets shown just fine.

Tried to move button outside gridview, and still inside updatepanel, but that did not change things.

So, my question is - is it possible to show-hide footer-header for a gridview inside updatepanel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind it again, after change the property.

Try to do something like:

```
grd.ShowFooter = true;
grd.ShowHeader = true;
grd.DataBind();
```

Take a look at this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1686452.aspx/1